# How to get information about process in C#?

Tags: c#, process

How to get information about process (cpu, memory, **disk & network** usage) in C# application?

P.S. System.Diagnostics.Process and System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter doesn't provide information about disk and network usage. I don't use it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "disk & network usage." Do you want the equivalent of "I/O Read Bytes" and "I/O Bytes Other" shown in task manager or something more?

Comment: Disk usage is a percentage that application using of the maximum possible activity of disk. Network usage is a percentage that application using of the maximum possible network speed.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

var currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
sb.AppendLine("Process information");
sb.AppendLine("-------------------");
sb.AppendLine("CPU time");
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("\tTotal       {0}",
    currentProcess.TotalProcessorTime));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("\tUser        {0}",
    currentProcess.UserProcessorTime));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("\tPrivileged  {0}",
    currentProcess.PrivilegedProcessorTime));
sb.AppendLine("Memory usage");
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("\tCurrent     {0:N0} B", currentProcess.WorkingSet64));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("\tPeak        {0:N0} B", currentProcess.PeakWorkingSet64));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Active threads      {0:N0}", currentProcess.Threads.Count));
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

As a starter this get a  list of all processes and loop over it:

```
    using System.Diagnostics;

    //...

    Process[] all = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process thisProc in all) {
      string Name = thisProc.ProcessName;
      //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your using list:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Now you can get a list of the processes with the `Process.GetProcesses()` method, as seen in this example:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process theprocess in processlist)
{
    Console.WriteLine(“Process: {0} ID: {1}”, theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
```

Comment: I know about it. But System.Diagnostic.Process doesn't provide information about disk network usage

Answer (score 0):

In System.Diagnostics there is a class called Process which allows you to statically get Processess by name, ID,etc.  So you can do something like

```
Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
int pageMemSize = p.PagedMemorySize;
```

There are a lot of different properties of the class. Look at the Process class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)